# Stripping/Recognizing dates via matplotlib and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am attempting to get Python to recognize a txt file containing data formatted like this

```
    20130501000000,1.55358,1.55371
    20130501000000,1.55357,1.55369
    20130501000000,1.55353,1.55367
    20130501000000,1.55349,1.55367
    20130501000000,1.55349,1.55367
```

Currently my script contains just

```
import time
import datetime
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

# Converter function
datefunc = lambda x: mdates.date2num(datetime.strptime(x, '%Y %m %d %H %M %S'))

# Read data from 'file.dat'
date, bid, ask = np.loadtxt('GBPUSD1d.txt',    # Data to be read
                              delimiter=',',  # First column is 19 characters wide
                              converters={0: datefunc}, # Formatting of column 0
                              dtype=float,   # All values are floats
                              unpack=True)   # Unpack to several variables
fig = plt.figure()
```

However my output it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/michaelsylvia/Documents/help.py", line 18, in <module>
    unpack=True)   # Unpack to several variables
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 985, in loadtxt
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
  File "/Users/michaelsylvia/Documents/help.py", line 11, in <lambda>
    datefunc = lambda x: mdates.date2num(datetime.strptime(x, '%Y %m %d %H %M %S'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 332, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '20130501000000' does not match format '%Y %m %d %H %M %S'
```

Comment: You should use pandas `read_csv` because your data is comma separated. It doesnt matter if its .txt file

Comment: It looks like your timestamp `'20130501000000'`'s year exceeds what python can handle.

Comment: What does pandas have to do with comma separated?  `loadtxt` works with comma separated text too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
datefunc = lambda x: mdates.date2num(datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
```

There are no spaces in your dates.

Comment: Worked - awesome! Thank you.